# Is there any way to insert the new 360 youtube videos in my android app?

Tags: android, youtube, android-youtube-api

I've looked everywhere but it doesn't to be any mention to it anywhere. I can reproduce them as any other video, but not see the 360 controls as in the youtube app.

Comment: may be you have to manually create the playlist in youtube account with all these 360 videos, and then you can fetch this playlist and do whatever you want